# Getting error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@DoctorID".'

Tags: vb.net

I've been searching for solution, but i couldn't find any.

And I've also refer to here *[Getting error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@EmployeeId".'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57882039/getting-error-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-must-declare-the-scalar-varia)*

But it doesn't seems to have a solution as well.

I keep having the error of 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@DoctorID".'

**MY SQL TABLE**

```
    [DoctorID] NVARCHAR (5)  NOT NULL,
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Gender]   NVARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [Email]    NVARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [Username] NVARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DoctorID] ASC)
);
```

**INSERTDATA**

```
    Public Function insertdata(ByVal qr As String) As Integer

        cmd = New SqlCommand(qr, con)
        con.Open()
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        Return i

    End Function
```

**MY CODE**

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        Dim qr As String

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DoctorID", txtDocID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cboGender.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)

        qr = "INSERT INTO Doctor (DoctorID, Name, Gender, Email, Username, Password) Values (@DoctorID, @Name, @Gender, @Email, @Username, @Password)"

        Dim logincorrect As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(insertdata(qr))
        If (logincorrect) Then
            MsgBox("Record Inserted Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("Something Wrong, Record Not Saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If

        disp_data()

    End Sub
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure that txtDocID.Text is not an empty string?

Comment: yes, i've no idea what's going on.
I've already declare the scalar variable, but is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep your database objects local to the method where they are used, you will save yourself a lot of headaches.

You are passing the query string to your `insertdata` function and then creating a `New` command. This new command knows nothing about the command that your added parameters to in the add button.

The `.Add` method for parameters is superior to `.AddWithValue`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Database objects that expose a `.Dispose` method need to be not only closed but disposed as they may contain unmanaged code. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for you even if there is an error.

```vb
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim rowsInserted As Integer
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string."),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Doctor (DoctorID, Name, Gender, Email, Username, Password) Values (@DoctorID, @Name, @Gender, @Email, @Username, @Password);", cn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@DoctorID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5).Value = txtDocID.Text
            .Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtName.Text
            .Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = cboGender.Text
            .Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = txtEmail.Text
            .Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = txtUsername.Text
            .Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = txtPassword.Text
        End With
        cn.Open()
        rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    If rowsInserted = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Record Inserted Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Else
        MsgBox("Something Wrong, Record Not Saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If
    disp_data()
End Sub
```

Comment: And so, do you mean that is it better not to use the insertdata function?

Comment: Certainly not in its present state. If you want to separate your UI code and data access code that is fine.